# GitLab modify existing runner to build from another branch that is not master

Tags: gitlab, branch, gitlab-ci-runner

software intern here, I want to temporarily change the branch from which we build and deploy our dev, I want to set it from master to i.e. branch1. So far I've changed the default branch in the GitLab repo from master to branch1 and here is how our .gitlab-ci.yml looks like:

```
build:dev:
  stage: build
  only:
    - branch1
  tags:
    - project-dev
  script:
    - docker-compose build

deploy:dev:
  stage: deploy
  only:
    - branch1
  tags:
    - project-dev
  script:
    - docker-compose stop server
    - docker-compose run server mix ecto.migrate
    - docker-compose up -d

upload-to-testfairy:
    stage: build
    only:
      - branch1
    tags:
      - project-simulant
    script:
       <doesn't really matter I guess>
```

I thought this would be enough, but no new jobs seem to be triggered and I can't find a way to trigger them manually either. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ops, my bad, turns out I hadn't updated the yml file in branch1 and it still waited for changes in master in order to build and deploy, after I updated the file in branch1 it automatically started building that commit in branch1.